# Multiple ACL on Cisco Catalyst with QoS classes - behaviour

Tags: cisco, qos, cisco-catalyst

I would like to limit the traffic to 2 Mbit for several IP addresses.
With the following configuration, will **each** IP be limited to 2 Mbit or is it all IP addresses **combined**?

Configuration:

```
access-list 100 remark cust_1
access-list 100 permit ip any host 192.168.1.10
access-list 100 permit ip host 192.168.1.10 any
access-list 100 remark cust_2
access-list 100 permit ip any host 172.16.23.2
access-list 100 permit ip host 172.16.23.2 any
access-list 100 remark cust_3
access-list 100 permit ip any host 10.10.10.75
access-list 100 permit ip host 10.10.10.75 any


class-map match-all cust_2M
  match access-group 100

policy-map Limit
  class cust_2M
    police aggregate cust_2M-limit

mls qos aggregate-policer cust_2M-limit 2048000 300000 exceed-action drop

interface FastEthernet0/1
service-policy input Limit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All IP Addresses will have a combined limit of 2Mbit

Comment: Right. My solution will clearly not work as intended then. The problem I'm facing is that the policy-map is limited to 8 classes, and I have many IP's that I would like to limit. If you know how to do this, please write a comment. I will accept this answer as solved within a week either way, since you answered my original question.

Comment: My new thread: http://serverfault.com/questions/252674/more-than-8-classes-in-a-policy-map-cisco-3560/252675#252675