# More than 8 classes in a policy-map - Cisco 3560

Tags: cisco, switch, ios, qos

It appears I am limited to 8 classes per policy-map.
Here is the error message when using the Cisco Network Assistant:

> The policy "policy-name" contains more
>   than 8 policers, which means it cannot
>   be attached to interfaces. Are you
>   sure you wish to apply this
>   configuration?

I currently use aggregate policers to limit the bandwidth. Is there a way to increase the allowed amount of classes, or is there a better way to control max allowed bandwidth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We came across this on the 3550 switches and unfortunately, the answer is "no", at least on the 3550s.

You essentially have to combine other policies (to trim the number down) which is what we did temporarily or spend a small fortune on higher-spec Cisco kit.

Comment: How do you mean combine other policies?

Comment: It would be great if you could further explain how you combined these policies. Thanks.

Comment: No problem at all, but I don't think it's the solution you're looking for unfortunately. I meant that if you have `Policy A with IPs 1, 2 and 3 using 20Mbps` and `Policy B with IPs 4, 5 and 6 using 5Mbps` then moving the IPs from Policy B to Policy A's pool, and simply adding its 5Mbps to Policy A's bandwidth to make it 25Mbps, frees up Policy B to be used elsewhere.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for. However, you did answer the original question. It is truly disappointing with hardware limitations like this.

Comment: I agree. Rather than spending a fortune on constantly upgrading Cisco kit constantly we now use `tc` on Linux and IMHO it does the job far better, for free.